# add data to <select> that is inside dialog

Tags: asp.net, xml, jquery

Script

```
xml="<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?><Questions>  <Question><Id>1</Id><Text>name1</Text></Question></Questions>";

var doc=$($.parseXML(xml));

$(doc).find("Question").each(function()
 { 

      alert($(this).find('Text').text());

       $('<%=sctQuestion.ClientID %>').
         append($("<option></option>").
          attr("value",$(this).find('Text').text()).
          text($(this).find('Text').text())); 

      });

 $("#dialog").dialog();
```

HTML

Inside MainMasterPage.aspx

```
<div id="dialog">
    <select runat="server" id="sctQuestion">
     <option></option>
    </select>
```

`</div>`

alert(); show me that correct information.

dialog Is open but empty `sctQuestion`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At a guess, you may be missing the `#` from the jquery selector

```
$('#<%=sctQuestion.ClientID %>').
     append($("<option></option>").
      attr("value",$(this).find('Text').text()).
      text($(this).find('Text').text())); 

});
```

Answer (score 1):

your appending to the select with a different ID...

do this:

```
$('#sctQuestion').
         append($("<option></option>").
          attr("value",$(this).find('Text').text()).
          text($(this).find('Text').text())); 

      });
```